# Layout Manager, or is there a better solution?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, ios

I have a table view where cells can display a variable amount of information. For example, the first cell could display 2 labels, the next cell 5 labels, and the third cell could display 1 label. The cell contents are stored in managed objects.

I would like to make this data driven, where I have a plist to configure the cells. I'm thinking that I can create a layout manager that reads in the config data and can intelligently determine how to display the labels.

Is there a better way to do this with UIKit? I realize that ultimately I could use Core Text to do the text rendering, but I would like for that to be an implementation detail. For starters I'd be happy with just have UILabels that are dynamically setup.

EDIT:

One side effect of making this driven from a configuration file is that I could update these configurations after the app has been deployed. I might consider generated xib files for download as well, but ideally I'd like to only delivery binary plists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're doing is configuring a single kind of table view cell with a variable number of labels, it seems like that's just a one-off piece of code for laying out the right number of labels. I can't quite tell from your question what your experience level with doing programmatic layout it; if you're new to doing UI outside of IB, let us know.

Speaking to the more varsity idea of a "layout manager", do consider that the NIB/XIB system is effectively a data-driven layout engine itself. If you're thinking about something that's generic enough to specify explicit layouts and properties of views, consider that that's what XIB files basically are-- a schematized XML layout. See the command line tool `ibtool`'s documentation (manpage [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ibtool/)) to learn more about how you can manipulate them.

If your layout needs are specific enough to your app but too general to handle with a set of fixed XIBs, then consider a lightweight manager like you describe. But I would think hard before going off and building something super-generic. The equivalent of [Zawinski's law](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html) here is that any layout manager will eventually end up incorporating more and more of the XIB functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm fairly experienced with iOS development and know my way around AppKit as well. I'll have a look at ibtool and see if there is something in there to help me out. Thanks!